# VueRouter not scrolling to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on a `Vue.js/Laravel8` project on a `single page app` and can't get `VueRouter` to get to scroll to the `section` I want. The page consists of different `sections` which are reachable if user scrolls down and I want the `viewport` to scroll to a `section` similar to how the `<a>` tag works.

How do I make

`<router-link :to="{ name: section1 }">Section1</router-link>`

behave like

`<a href="#section1">Section1</a>`?

I've tried the following:

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap')

import Vue from "vue"
import App from "../vue/app"
import router from "./router";

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: { App },
    router
});
```

**router.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Home from "../vue/home";
import Section1 from "../vue/section1";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter ({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {path: "/", name: "home"},
        {path: "/section1", name: "section1", component: Section1},
    ],
    scrollBehavior(to, from,  savedPosition) {
        console.log(savedPosition)
        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else if (to.hash) {
            return {
                selector: to.hash
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**web.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**app.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <home></home>
      <section1></section1>
    </main>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

**navigation.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'section1' }">Section1</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

**section1.vue:**

```
<template>
  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </section>
</template>
```

`<router-link>` tags are correctly converted into `<a>` tags in the browser and `VueRouter` applies following `properties` to the clicked `anchor`:

`class="router-link-exact-active"`

`class="router-link-active"`

`aria-current="page"`

But the `viewport` is not scrolling to the desired `section` still. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use path insted of name and add hash to link:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/section1', hash: '#section1' }">Section1</router-link>
```

Comment: Hey, this works! Thank you. Just replacing `name: 'section1'` with `hash: 'section1'` made the scroll work. Any way to remove the ugly `#` symbol from the `/#section1` browser url?